# Trying to install CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to use CPAN, but I am running into an issue. First I did `sudo apt-get install perl`. It says it's there. I typed `cpan` `install automatically yes` `sudo` which indicated as done, and I can get into `cpan`. I downloaded the `.pl` I wanted to use on CPAN, pointed to the directory, and tried `perl file.pl`. I am presented with this message:

```
Can't locate CAM/ODF.pm in @INC (@INC containes /etc/per/ /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14/ .usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at file.pl in line 7
```

I downloaded `CAM-PDF-1.59.tar.gz`, double clicked, and tried placing the contents in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, but I am getting `you don't have the right permissions`.

How should I install CPAN on Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) to use in the terminal? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, you're mixing up quite a few things here.

- `cpan` is an installer for Perl modules from the CPAN, and it is installed by default
- You don't download CPAN packages manually, but do `cpan CAM::PDF' to install from CPAN.
- `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` is a very strange place to put these things, better delete that again.

But all of that is not needed, as Ubuntu ships [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.52/lib/CAM/PDF.pm#DESCRIPTION):

```
sudo apt-get install libcam-pdf-perl
```

Generally, if a Perl library is named `Foo::Bar` on CPAN, the Debian/Ubuntu package will be named `libfoo-bar-perl`. Use these packages before trying to install them with `cpan` from CPAN.

Comment: the file says `use CAM::PDF;`.  If I am understanding you correctly I should change this line to `use libcam-pdf-perl`?

Comment: No, you don't change the script. I was only talking about installing the appropriate packages so CAM::PDF gets installed.